# Return anything other than null

Tags: java, spring, spring-config

My code used to work until I added the sslEnabled configuration. Since I put "false" as the default value for sslEnabled, it will return null.

And that null causes me the following:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'servletContainer' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean'

I tried to `return new ServletWebServerFactory();` but says Cannot instantiate the type ServletWebServerFactory

```
@Configuration
public class ConnectorConfig {

@Value("${security.ssl.enabled}")
private boolean sslEnabled;

/**
 * Servlet container.
 *
 * @return the servlet web server factory
 */
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    if(sslEnabled) {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }
    return null;
}
....
```

Basically if the flag `sslEnabled` is false I don't want to enable the SSL and I want to skip that configuration

Comment: seeing as you hardcoded your method to return null if that flag is set to false, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @Stultuske I know... I just want a solution for it

Comment: Use optional? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the simplest thing to do is declaring a wrapper class and injecting that class. Like creating the following bean:

```
public class ServletWebServerFactoryWrapper {

    private ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory;

    public ServletWebServerFactoryWrapper(ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory){
        this.servletWebServerFactory = servletWebServerFactory;
    }

    public static ServletWebServerFactoryWrapper getWrapper(ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory){
        return new ServletWebServerFactoryWrapper(servletWebServerFactory);
    }

    public ServletWebServerFactory getFactory(){
        return servletWebServerFactory;
    }
}
```

and returning it in your code:

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactoryWrapper servletContainer() {
    if(sslEnabled) {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        return ServletWebServerFactoryWrapper.getWrapper(tomcat);
    }
    return ServletWebServerFactoryWrapper.getWrapper(null);
}
```

I don't know if you ca use an `Optional<ServletWebServerFactory>` (Java 8), but you can try, it should be pretty equivalent to this. Your method should become the following:

```
@Bean
public Optional<ServletWebServerFactory> servletContainer() {
    if(sslEnabled) {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        return Optional.of(tomcat);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Remember that this last alternative works only on Java 8 or superior.

Comment: your wrapper has issues

Comment: @user10867569 please tell me what issues, I'll be happy to fix them.

Comment: Just copy to eclipse and u see your code has syntax issues

Comment: Done, check it.

Comment: I did that but this code starts SSL configuration anyway.

Comment: I don't why it starts SSL configuration anyway, but I suspect that it is related to something else. You should debug your application to understand why it starts SSL anyway. But probably it is another issue and it may not related to the `BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException` you asked for.

Comment: Why not just use optional? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: @BhathiyaPerera I don't know if he uses Java 8 or less... however I added an example with java 8's Optional.